# no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, spring-transactions

I am using spring 4.1.1 for my project,i am getting the following exception. Given below are the definitions i am using , need help!

```
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd"
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the spring-tx dependency on your classpath. If you are using maven add the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If you already have the dependency check the version as it might not be 4.1.

You can also declare your namespace omitting the version so that it always picks the latest

```
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
```

Specify the version if you really need some feature specific to the version

Comment: after adding spring-tx the error was resolved but now i am getting new exception as follows  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor